# Помогите понять что означает написанное кода

Tags: c++, массивы

Пожалуйста объясните как это получилось или что означает каждая написаная часть

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

int rrand(int range_min, int range_max) {
    return rand() % (range_max - range_min + 1) + range_min;
}

const unsigned int a = 10;
const int b = 100;

int ary[a];

int main(void) {

    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(time(NULL)));
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
        ary[i] = rrand(-b, b);
    }
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
        cout << "Значение элемента массива [" << i << "] = " << ary[i] << endl;
    }

    int min_val = ary[0];
    unsigned int min_idx = 0;
    for (unsigned int i = 1; i < a; i++) {
        if (min_val > ary[i]) {
            min_val = ary[i];
            min_idx = i;
        }
    }
    cout << "Минимальное значение " << min_val << ", индекс элемента " << min_idx << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Просто интересно, чем вызван данный вопрос. Преподаватель не принял чужой код? :)

Comment: @Harry хочу понять написанное и все.(вы правы)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int rrand(int range_min, int range_max) {
    return rand() % (range_max - range_min + 1) + range_min;
}
```

Это функция, принимающая 2 аргумента, и возвращающая случайное число в заданных пределах.

```
const unsigned int a = 10; // переменная (число)
const int b = 100; // переменная (число)

int ary[a]; // массив размера a (a = 10)
```

Это объявления глобальных переменных и массива, так как объявления происходят вне функции, соответственно они будут доступны во всех функциях данного файла.

```
int main(void) {

    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(time(NULL))); // это нужно для того, чтобы работал random. Мы берем текущее машинное время для генерации случайного числа
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < a; i++) { // в этих 3 строчках мы 10 раз (потому что a = 10) пробегаемся по массиву ary и заполняем его случайными числами от -b до b, то есть от -100 до 100 (так как b = 100)
        ary[i] = rrand(-b, b);
    }
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < a; i++) { // а в этих 3 - выводим эти сгенерированные значения в консоль
        cout << "Значение элемента массива [" << i << "] = " << ary[i] << endl;
    }

    int min_val = ary[0]; // создаем переменную, в которой будет храниться минимальное число в массиве и приравниваем его к первому элементу массива (не факт, что этот элемент массива будет минимальным числом, с таким же успехом мы могли бы написать int min_val = 0, но лучше так не делать, так как может так получиться, что среди сгенерированных чисел массива все будут больше 0 и тогда программа выдаст нам ответ 0, который будет неверным)
    unsigned int min_idx = 0; // создаем переменную для хранения индекса минимального  числа
    for (unsigned int i = 1; i < a; i++) { // пробегаемся по массиву (пропускаем самый первый элемент с индексом 0, так как мы и так приравняли его значение в переменную min_val и его можно пропустить)
        if (min_val > ary[i]) { // если текущее значение переменной min_val в цикле больше чем текущий элемент массива (а мы пробегаемся по каждому, кроме самого первого), то тогда переменная min_val примет это новое значение (то есть значение станет меньше, нам же нужно найти минимальное значение)
            min_val = ary[i];
            min_idx = i;
        }
    }
    cout << "Минимальное значение " << min_val << ", индекс элемента " << min_idx << endl; // выводим в консоль это минимальное значение

    system("pause"); // после завершения программы консоль автоматически закроется, а эта строчка заморозит консоль, пока вы ее сами не закроете
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Массив заполняется случайными числами, после в цикле находится минимальное значение из всего массива и выводится вместе с индексом.

Comment: Строгое общественность, следящая за порядком на форуме, сейчас объяснит, что это не ответ, а комментарий, однако на мой взгляд, это именно тот ответ, которого заслуживает, данный вопрос :). От меня '+'

Comment: @АлександрМуксимов ладно, не буду пытаться закрывать)